# Can we write star programs in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

I am new to power-shell and was practicing some programs. Please let me know if I can write * programs in Powershell. I know its a scripting tool and used in System Administration. To grasp the basic, I am trying this script.

Here the code that I have written :

```
cls
for ($i = 1; $i -le 4 ;$i++)
{
for ($j = 1; $j -le $i; $j++){
write-host "*"
}

write-host "`n"
}
```

> Desired Output :
>
> *
>
> *
>   *
>
> *
>   *
>   *
>
> *
>   * 
>   *
>   *

I am getting the output as :

[image: Actual Output]

Can anyone help me on this. Your help will highly be appreciated.

> SOLVED
>
> ```
> cls
> for ($i = 1; $i -le 4 ;$i++)
> {
> for ($j = 1; $j -le 4 ; $j++){
> write-host "*" -NoNewline
> }
>
> write-host "`n"
> }
> ```

Comment: Read the docs for `Write-Host`, it is interesting.

Comment: Thanks @Mat only using -NoNewLine, it solved the issue. I should have gone through the documentation.

Comment: another solution to the "growing line of characters" problem is to use `string multiplication`. yes, that is really a thing! [*grin*] try this >>> `'=' * 20` <<< to see what i mean. you can use your `for` index to multiply the base string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution you posted did not work for me. [*frown*] it gave 4 lines of 4 asterisks, each separated from the others by one blank line.

this version uses a `foreach` loop, iterates thru the desired number of lines, draws a line that is built by using string multiplication, inserts one blank line, and then repeats for each remaining line in the line count.

```
$LineCount = 8
$LineChar = '*'

foreach ($LC_Item in 1..$LineCount)
    {
    Write-Host ($LineChar * $LC_Item)
    Write-Host
    }
```

output ...

```
*

**

***

****

*****

******

*******

********
```

Comment: Hi, would you please explain me 1..$LineCount line. It would be helpful for me.

Comment: @Sampad `..` is the _range_ operator - `$a..$b` generates an array of all the integers from `$a` to `$b`, inclusive

Comment: @Sampad - as MathiasR.Jessen mentioned, it is the range operator. 1..<something that evaluates to a number>` will give you that range of items. i the case of my code, it gives 1 thru 8 and the `foreach` iterates thru that range of numbers. [*grin*]

Answer (score 2):

That's a lot of code for this task. PowerShell allows for many way to accomplish the same or similar tasks. As for your effort, this can be easily simplified to a one liner. No write-Host needed.

```
# Use the range operator, pipe to a ForEach with a string repeat '*' X times per the range number passed in.

1..8 | ForEach{('*')*$PSItem}

# Results
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
```

***Update to include the blank lines.***

Hey Lee, yep terse, and I missed the needed blank line. Easily fixed with...

```
# Use the range operator, pipe to a ForEach with a string repeat '*' X times per the range number passed in and a blank line for each pass
1..8 | ForEach{('*')*$PSItem + "`n"}

# Results

*

**

***

****

*****

******

*******

********
```